# Utuntu 18.04 - Super + Number keys aren't working when "Dash to panel" is active

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

So when the standard dash for Ubuntu is activated, I can switch to applications via <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> Keys and so on.
But I installed Tweaks and then activated the "Dash to panel" option and customized it all to look a little more like Windows:

[image: screenshot]

Then I noticed, that as soon as I activate this option, the Hotkeys for <kbd>Super</kbd> + [Number] seem to stop working. Nothing happens.

Other hotkeys like <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> work just fine.

Is there any way around this? I don't mind using something different to Tweaks Dash To Panel. It apparently doesn't support the taskbar on 2 monitors anyway.

Comment: can confirm, same happens with me!

Comment: any leads on this? It is an issue that is quite troubling me.

Answer (score 3):

I found a fix:

(works as of March 13th 2019, Ubuntu 18.10)

1) Install Dash-to-Panel via https://extensions.gnome.org

- You might need to install an addon for Firefox (prompt from website)
- You might also need to enable the website for Gnome Shell integration. The site will ask you to visit this page: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation

I know it says "chrome install guide" but the command also enables support for Firefox. The command is at the bottom.

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```

2) click the blue 'gear and wrench' icon next to the On/Off switch - A settings window for the extension appears.

3) Go to the "Behaviour" tab

4) At the bottom, enable "Use hotkeys to activate app"

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out the reason. When you login, choose Gnome Classic instead of Ubuntu Gnome. In that session things will work as expected. Let me know if that worked for you.